# Center text in a Toast

Tags: android, text, alignment, center, android-toast

I was wondering if there was a way to display all text in a `Toast` to be centered. For instance, I have a `Toast` that has 2 lines of text in it. For purely aesthetic reasons, I would like the text to **center-aligned** instead of left-aligned. I've looked through the documentation and can't find anything about it. Is there a simple way to do this that I have missed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the Toast's `setView(view)` function to supply a `View` with `Gravity.CENTER`.

Comment: What about APIs < 23? Does it matter?

Answer (score 112):

Adapted from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687666/how-to-set-color-of-toast-text):

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Centered\nmessage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
if( v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Why the default gravity is not Gravity.CENTER? Silly android!

Comment: I don't know why but I have failed this method on Android 11 (API-30).

Comment: I haven't worked with Android for years, it's possible that Google disabled this possibility?

Answer (score 28):

Toast is built on a TextView and the default gravity of it is left aligned. So, you need to create your own TextView like this for instance :

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="all the text you want"
/>
```

And you assign the TextView to the Toast like this :

```
Toast t = new Toast(yourContext);
t.setView(yourNewTextView);
```

Answer (score 28):

Without the hacks:

```
String text = "Some text";
Spannable centeredText = new SpannableString(text);
centeredText.setSpan(
    new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER),
    0, text.length() - 1,
    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
);

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), centeredText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

There are also another alignments besides center.

cf. [Multiple alignment in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612380/3726383)

Comment: It still works on Android 11 (API-30).

Answer (score 19):

It is dirty hack, but

```
((TextView)((LinearLayout)toast.getView()).getChildAt(0))
    .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Great! Make sure you surround with a `ClassCastException` catch to be safe in case the view hierarchy of Toasts changes in the future.

Comment: This works on my Nexus 4. I suggest doing this, wrapping it with a ClassCastException as Max Howell said above and then live with it when it throws an actual exception.

Comment: use findViewById(android.R.id.message) on the view returned by toast.getView() to ensure working code on all versions

Answer (score 13):

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: This does not center the text, but the toast's itself.

Answer (score 5):

Not saing that `findViewById(android.R.id.message)` is wrong, but just in case there are (future?) implementation differences I myself used a bit differen approach:

```
void centerText(View view) {
    if( view instanceof TextView){
        ((TextView) view).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }else if( view instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
        int n = group.getChildCount();
        for( int i = 0; i<n; i++ ){
            centerText(group.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
centerText(t.getView());
t.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

In **kotlin**:

```
fun makeToast(context: Context, resId: Int) {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(context, resId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    val view = toast.view.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.message)
    view?.let {
        view.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    }
    toast.show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is work for me:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER| Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 20);
toast.show();
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The text is still aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0):

This variation is with using `LinearLayout` in your layout xml :)

```
Toast SampleToast = Toast.makeText(this, "This is the example of centered text.\nIt is multiline text.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
LinearLayout OurLayout = (LinearLayout) SampleToast.getView();
    
if (OurLayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
   TextView SampleView = (TextView) OurLayout.getChildAt(0);
   SampleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}

SampleToast.show();
```

Comment: This is a hacky solution that might not work in future versions of android, for example if the first child is not a TextView. Does not follow Java coding standards.

Answer (score -3):

```
Toast t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.setText("Password Does't match...");
t.setGravity(0, 0, 0);
t.show();
```

simple code for toast most be center

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look through the [help page on answering questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). As written, your code is poorly formatted and does not contain an explanation.

Comment: Sorry, but your code set gravity center to the toast (it appear in center screen), not to the text