# ITextPdf: Printing Arabic strings from Right To Left (RTL)

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, arabic, right-to-left

I use iTextpdf on java in order to generate stamped PDFs, sometimes the generated PDF is in Arabic and I am facing a funny problem.
To let the Arabic page being created from Right To Left (RTL) I use tables and cells which have the property `PdfPCell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL)`. When I use this property Arabic does not show at all, if I avoid the call to this property Arabic strings are correctly showed, this means I shouldn't have problems with fonts and I don't really know if this is an issue with iText or I'm just missing something.

Here a small piece of code which shows an Arabic string correctly:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(Application.getBASEPATH() + "fonts/arabic.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font trebuchetSmaller = new Font(bf, 10, 0);

PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(1); 
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(new Phrase("ربط صفحة على شبكة الإنترنت"), trebuchetSmaller));
cell.addElement(paragraph);
tbl.addCell(cell);
```

Here the needed change which makes the Arabic string disappear:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(Application.getBASEPATH() + "fonts/arabic.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font trebuchetSmaller = new Font(bf, 10, 0);

PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(1); 
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(new Phrase("ربط صفحة على شبكة الإنترنت"), trebuchetSmaller));
cell.addElement(paragraph);
tbl.addCell(cell);
```

If I use `PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL` with an English string it shows correctly in the format it has supposed to be. If I use a string with mixed English and Arabic characters just the English ones are showed.

Comment: You can use Spannabe.
[There is more information about it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11612380/1278748

Answer (score 6):

Change your code to include the registered font:

```
new Phrase("آزمايش", font)
```

Also you can add the phrase directly:

```
PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("آزمايش", font));  
pdfCell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: This is itext 5 sample. What about itext 7. How can we change direction in itext 7?

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/clone-language-specific-examples

Comment: I've tested it, no changes, I see my text left to right with separated words!

Comment: If you are looking for a .NET Core version with RTL support, try https://github.com/VahidN/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot.
Actually the problem was the font used that when switched in RTL was behaving bad. I found a lot of very interesting unicode arabic fonts at this address: http://cooltext.com/Fonts-Unicode-Arabic for whoever is interested.

Comment: Hi there, can you help me?! I want to create a pdf in Arabic and wont to make text start from right to left, with the code above the arabic character is separated and vise versa also from LTR