# how to create Persian PDF with iText

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans

I know that many people may have asked this question before. I've read almost all of them`but it couldn't help me solve my problem. 
I'm using iText java library to generate a Persian PDF. I'm using the following

how to use `PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL`

code:

```
String ruta = txtruta.getText();
    String contenido= txtcontenido.getText();
    try {
        FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(ruta+".pdf");
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,50,50);
          PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, archivo);
          doc.open();
          BaseFont bfComic = BaseFont.createFont("D:\\Font\\B Lotus.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
          Font font = new Font(bfComic, 12,Font.NORMAL);
           doc.add(new Paragraph(contenido,font));
       doc.close();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ok");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Eroor"+e);    
    }
```

**Output:**
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcR9E.png)

Comment: Can you ask the exact question in the body of the question? The more you explain your question, the better chances to get great help :) Good luck!

Comment: I want to text RTL when save in the pdf

Comment: My problem now RTL Text

Answer (score 2):

`Document.add()` doesn't support RTL text. You'll have to use `ColumnText.setRunDirection` or `PdfPTable.setRunDirection`.

Comment: I do not know Use ColumnText.setRunDirection , PdfPTable.setRunDirection
plz help me 
. Please write the code for me 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Persian language. But, I think your problem will be with the font (**B Lotus.ttf**) you used. In most of times using a registered Unicode font may solve the problem. Try again using a different font.

Also you can RTL a text phrase using following code.

> PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(contenido, myUnicodePersianFont));
>   pdfCell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);

You will find out a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122610/itextpdf-printing-arabic-strings-from-right-to-left-rtl).

Comment: If you found this answer is solving your problem, please be kind enough to up vote the answer or mark as  “accepted”. Honestly saying, here I'm looking for some reputation in the website. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**I succeeded**

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

      JFileChooser dlg = new JFileChooser();
               int option = dlg.showSaveDialog(this);
               if(option==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                  File f = dlg.getSelectedFile();
                  txtaddress.setText(f.toString());
               }
    
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
    String ruta = txtaddress.getText();
    String con= content.getText();
    try {
          FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(ruta+".pdf");
          Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,50,50);
          PdfWriter Writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, archivo);
          doc.open();
          LanguageProcessor al = new ArabicLigaturizer();
          Writer.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
          BaseFont bfComic = BaseFont.createFont("D:\\Font\\titr.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
          Font font = new Font(bfComic, 12,Font.NORMAL);
          Paragraph p = new Paragraph(al.process(con),font);
          p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
          doc.add(p);
          doc.close();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Yes");
       
    } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Eroor"+e);    
    }
     
}
```