# Arabic letters data in exporting data to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, arabic

this is my code

```
Cell cellColss = new Cell();    
BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"D:\ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfArialUniCode, 12);
Chunk chunkColss = new Chunk("مسلسل",font);
cellColss.Add(chunkColss);
pdfTable.AddCell(cellColss);
```

Exported, the data looks like this:
[image: formatted data]

it appears "مسلسل" as "ل س ل س م"

after I added this code

```
PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("مسلسل", font));
pdfCell.RunDirection=PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
```

instead of

```
Chunk chunkColss = new Chunk("مسلسل",font);`
```

appears nothing

Note :- 
I install the last recent Version of iTextShare

This is the Full Code

```
  Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 40, 25);
            System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, mStream);
            int cols = dataTable.Columns.Count;
            int rows = dataTable.Rows.Count;
            pdfDoc.Open();

            iTextSharp.text.Table pdfTable = new iTextSharp.text.Table(3, rows);
            pdfTable.BorderWidth = 1;
            pdfTable.Width = 100;
            pdfTable.Padding = 1;
            pdfTable.Spacing = 1;
            BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"D:\ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfArialUniCode, 12);           
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Cell cellColss = new Cell();               
                    Chunk chunkColss = new Chunk("مسلسل", font);
                    string ss = "مسلسل";
                    string bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder().ToString();
                    PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(chunkColss));
                    pdfCell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
                   cellColss.Add(pdfCell);
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cellColss);
                }

                if (dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Barcode")
                {
                    Cell cellCols = new Cell();
                    Chunk chunkCols = new Chunk("باركود", font);
                    cellCols.Add(chunkCols);
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cellCols);
                }
                else if (dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Description")
                {
                    Cell cellCols = new Cell();
                    Chunk chunkCols = new Chunk("اسم الصنف بالعربى والانجليزى", font);
                    cellCols.Add(chunkCols);
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cellCols);
                }

            }
           for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        Cell cellRows1 = new Cell();                       
                        Chunk chunkRows2 = new Chunk((k + 1).ToString(), font);
                        cellRows1.Add(chunkRows2);
                        pdfTable.AddCell(cellRows1);
                    }

                    if (dataTable.Columns[j].ColumnName == "Barcode") 
                    {
                        Cell cellRows = new Cell();                      
                        Chunk chunkRows = new Chunk(dataTable.Rows[k][j].ToString(), font);
                        cellRows.Add(chunkRows);
                        pdfTable.AddCell(cellRows);
                    }
                    else if (dataTable.Columns[j].ColumnName == "Description")
                    {
                        Cell cellRows = new Cell();                       
                        Chunk chunkRows = new Chunk(dataTable.Rows[k][j].ToString(), font);
                        cellRows.Add(chunkRows);
                        pdfTable.AddCell(cellRows);

                    }
                }
            }

            pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.pdf");
            Response.Clear();
            Response.BinaryWrite(mStream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
```

Comment: @BrunoLowagie this answer didn't solve the problem

Comment: It's always a bad idea not to use the Unicode notation. Anyway: it works for us. There's no problem to solve. Maybe you're not using a recent / official version of iTextSharp.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I already have the recent version I install `Install-Package itextsharp`

Comment: Did you check the [download page](http://developers.itextpdf.com/downloads). iTextSharp 5.5.9 has support for Arabic, but it takes some work to use it; iText 7 for C# has better support for Arabic, but you need the closed source [pdfCalligraph](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) add on.

Comment: We no longer talk of iTextSharp. Since iText 7, we talk about iText 7 for C#.

Comment: @Bruno he uses the command line NuGet to get the latest version from nuget.org, which is currently 5.5.9.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I update the Question with full Code, Could you have  a look again? ...  3 days wasted :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about it, I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("مسلسل", font));  
pdfCell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

A similar example it is in the following link :
[ITextPdf: Printing Arabic strings from Right To Left (RTL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122610/itextpdf-printing-arabic-strings-from-right-to-left-rtl)

Comment: it appears nothing when I add this code instead of `Chunk chunkColss = new Chunk("مسلسل",font);`