# Need to center-align a single portion of text in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, spannablestring

I'm currently using SpannableString to format a large block of text in a single TextView. The size and color are formatted just fine, but I'm struggling with alignment.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654022/multiple-alignment-in-textview) that gave guidance on formatting for alignment, as well as [this Android Developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.Alignment.html) on how to use AlignmentSpan, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Eclipse shows no errors, the app loads/runs just fine, but the alignment piece seems to be completely ignored. Here's my code:

```
Spannable t = new SpannableString("Test Blue.");
t.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_blue)), 0, t.length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
t.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.big_text)), 0, t.length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
t.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, t.length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text3.setText(t);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

[Edit] I've also tried commenting out both the color and size setSpans to see if there's a conflict, but no luck.

[Edit 2]: I marked the below answer as correct, but the correct answer is actually buried in the comments. I failed to update my XML file width for the TextView to match_parent (instead of fill_content). Thanks Serge!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could try to do this:

```
String t = "<center><font color=\"blue\">Test Blue.</font></center>";
text3.setText(Html.fromHtml(t));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, serge. This didn't work for me either. I was using HTML before trying Spannable strings, and couldn't find a satisfactory way to handle text size. To be clear, though, I did try your suggestion, but it didn't center the text either. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: I see, ill keep looking

Comment: Mybe you did not set your text width in XML to match parent so it doesn't have any room to center it inside the TextView

Comment: Wow, good catch. I did change the XML to match_parent, but it still isn't centering. I figured that would fix it.

Comment: My mistake! That actually did fix the problem, but I edited the wrong file. I edited the correct file, and now it works beautifully. Serge, I'm new around here...should I mark this answer as correct, or would you prefer to provide another answer (to change XML to match_parent) and I can check that one?