# Android Set the text align to the middle of the toast

Tags: android, android-view

I have a toast message which is pretty long. I would like to set the text in the middle and not to start align to the left.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Toast is built on a TextView and the default gravity of it is left aligned. So, you need to create your own TextView like this for instance :

```
<TextView       
android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"     
android:text="all the text you want" />
```

And you assign the TextView to the Toast like this :

```
Toast t = new Toast(yourContext); 
t.setView(yourNewTextView);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522023/center-text-in-a-toast-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Than you @dmytrodanylyk but I woul like to set the text inside of the toast in the middle and not all the toast.