# Left Aligning Text in Toast Android

Tags: java, android, toast

I have a toast which shows text as centered align and i want to make it left align how can it be done. The code for generation of toast is as follows.

```
Toast test;
String final_status = titles[status_index];
String final_equipment = EquipmentNamePartial[equipment_index];
test = Toast.makeText(SalesBar.this, "Status: " + final_status + '\n'
         + " Equipment: " + final_equipment + '\n'
         + " Duration: " + duration_value + " hours", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
test.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, xx, yy);
test.show();
```

Comment: have you got any exception or not getting desired result ?

Comment: no toast is generating fine and on the exact location where i touch on the screen. The problem is that text inside it center aligned and i want it to be left aligned.

Comment: believe me Antrromet iam scratching my head as well on this

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176092/android-set-the-text-align-to-the-middle-of-the-toast

Answer (score 2):

Create Custom Toast Message.

```
TextView textview = new TextView(context);
textview.setText(text);
textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
textview.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setView(textview);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a View and use Toast.setView.
The simplest case is to create a TextView and set it's gravity

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Toast` with custom layout:

```
Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setView(toastRoot);
toast.show();
```

Here is some samples: http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/161, http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-customize-toasts