# Toast UI isn't showing up properly

Tags: android, android-toast

The toast is populating but the text is getting cut. There is some issue in UI. Please see screenshot.

[This is from my APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl1Te.jpg)

I am using the following line to show toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.selectplan), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Also tried smaller text same issue. I have another APP I have put the same toast code it is coming up properly.

[From another APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwjTA.jpg)

What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center text in a toast in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522023/center-text-in-a-toast-in-android)

Comment: you can create customized toast

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei: Why is this happening when it is perfect in a different app.

Comment: in other app toast text is centered (customized toast) but in your app text is aligned to left (default toast)

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei: I created the other APP. toast is the default. I haven't customized it.

Comment: @RAMKUMAR  if you use same text length in your new app you gonna see the problem again ! i don't know why but it seems your device default toast view can't handle the given text length the solution that comes to my mind is to create Toast with custom view

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei: Hmmmm.. that is strange. Thanks. I will use the given solution. thanks again all.

Answer (score -2):

This sometimes happen . i  got the same Probleme in my P9 when i was running it . i think it Depends on the  android version i think . got fixed by herself after Updating the JDK