# How to Align Android Toast as Centered

Tags: android, toast, text-alignment, android-toast

### How to Align Android Toast as Centered

I saw many related questions in StackOverflow and All over the Internet, but they align the toast centered to the display. But, **I want to display the text-centered to my toast!**

---

[image: Example Image]

### **My Code to display my Toast**

```
   timeout_on = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Screen Timeout is Enabled (Your screen will doesn't sleep from now!)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   timeout_on.show();
```

Comment: Do you want to center the toast or the toast's text ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center text in a toast in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522023/center-text-in-a-toast-in-android)

Comment: @Programmerabc I want to center the Toast's Text!

Comment: Can, Anybody Plz start a bounty for my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Try the following:

```
Toast timeout_on = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Screen Timeout is Enabled (Your screen will doesn't sleep from now!)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
TextView v = (TextView) timeout_on.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
if( v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
timeout_on.show();
```

This code gets the instance of the TextView inside of your Toast and gives you more room for customization *(like setting your text's gravity/alignment)*.

Answer adopted from [Marc's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13492794/15590269)

Answer (score 1):

kotlin:

```
val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
toast.show()
```

java:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Your code is useful when centering the toast. But I want to center my Toast's text only!

Answer (score 0):

Toast is built on a TextView and as you can see by default is left aligned. Create your own text view with the alignment you want and set it to your Toast view

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="all the text you want"
/>
```

And you assign the TextView to the Toast like this :

```
Toast t = new Toast(yourContext);
t.setView(yourNewTextView);
```